# WS2812B Led Digital Panel Matrix Flexible Screen 8*8. Some LEDs that are not supposed to, switch on

Tags: led, esp32

My project is composed of an ESP32, a level converter and two WS2812B Led Digital Panel Matrix Flexible Screen 8*8 (from Aliexpress) interconnected with the provided cable. My objective is to show a score, no scrolling or any other animation.

The main functionality works ok, I can display any decimal number between 00 to 99 (one digit in each 8x8 panel).

My problem is that apart from the digits printed, some not so aleatory LEDs switch on, not necessarily on the same color as the intended number, nor on the selected luminosity. Changing the number changes this undesirable pattern that seems to repeat for the same number on the same 8x8 matrix. Problem patters does not follow a specific 8x8 matrix, the problem does not seem to be in the hardware.

The level converter converts the ESP32 3.3v to 5v required by the Matrix but even before I connected the level converter the problem was the same.

The code I am using is as below:

```
#include <Adafruit_NeoPixel.h>
#ifdef __AVR__
  #include <avr/power.h>
#endif
 
// Which pin on the Arduino is connected to the NeoPixels?
#define PIN            14
 
// How many NeoPixels are attached to the Arduino?
#define NUMPIXELS      128
 
Adafruit_NeoPixel pixels = Adafruit_NeoPixel(NUMPIXELS, PIN, NEO_GRB + NEO_KHZ800);
 
int delayval = 10; // delay for half a second
 
void setup() {
  pixels.begin(); // This initializes the NeoPixel library.
}
 
void loop() {
 
  // For a set of NeoPixels the first NeoPixel is 0, second is 1, all the way up to the count of pixels minus one.
  pixels.clear();  
  pixels.setBrightness(1);

  boolean N0[8][8] PROGMEM = {{0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0},{0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0},{0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0},{0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0},{0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0},{0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0},{0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0},{0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0}};    
  boolean N1[8][8] PROGMEM = {{0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0},{0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0},{0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0},{0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0},{0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0},{0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0},{0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0},{0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0}};
  boolean N2[8][8] PROGMEM = {{0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0},{0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0},{0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0},{0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0},{0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0},{0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0}};
  boolean N3[8][8] PROGMEM = {{0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0},{0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0},{0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0},{0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0},{0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0},{0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0}};  
  boolean N4[8][8] PROGMEM = {{0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0},{0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0},{0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0},{1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0},{0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},{0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0},{0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0},{0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0}};
  boolean N5[8][8] PROGMEM = {{0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0},{0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0},{0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0},{0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0},{0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0},{0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0},{0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0},{0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0}};  
  boolean N6[8][8] PROGMEM = {{0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0},{0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0},{0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0},{0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0},{0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0},{0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0},{0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0},{0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0}}; 
  boolean N7[8][8] PROGMEM = {{0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0},{0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0},{0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0},{0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0},{0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0}};    
  boolean N8[8][8] PROGMEM = {{0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0},{0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0},{0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0},{0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0},{0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0},{0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0},{0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0},{0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0}};  
  boolean N9[8][8] PROGMEM = {{0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0},{0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0},{0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0},{0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0},{0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0},{0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0},{0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0}};    

  int counter = 0;
  for(int line=0;line<8;line++){
    for(int column=0;column<8;column++){
      if(N2[line][column]==1){
        pixels.setPixelColor(counter, pixels.Color(0,255,0));
        pixels.show();      
        delay(delayval);
      }

      if(N1[line][column]==1){
        pixels.setPixelColor(counter+64, pixels.Color(255,33,255));
        pixels.show();      
        delay(delayval);
      }     
      
      counter++;
    }
  }
  while(1){};
}
```

This is a non optimized code for testing purposes only.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How are you providing power to the LED matrices?

Comment: Computer USB. That is why I set brightness to 1 but even if I set it to 10 the problem remains the same, or, the unwanted leds that switch on are the same.

Comment: Just to add, say number 5 when printed comes along two LEDs I did not order on. Say I print a green 5. Then I get this blue faint one in a certain position and a bright red one somewhere else. This pattern will repeat no matter what I do, even if I print the 5 on pink for instance, the faint blue and the bright red will be there, even if I change the 8x8 tile.

Comment: If instead of 5 I print one other number, foreign LEDs will be different and curiously number one comes out clean. changing brightness from 10 to 1 makes no difference except for the brightness of those I control.

Answer (score 3):

Found the Adafruit NeoPixel is the reason for the problem (or the way it is implemented above is not the best).

Solved with the fastLED library as below:

```
#include "FastLED.h"
#define NUM_LEDS 128
#define DATA_PIN 14
#define BRIGHTNESS 10
CRGB leds[NUM_LEDS];
int delayval = 10; // delay for half a second

boolean N0[8][8] PROGMEM = {{0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0},{0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0},{0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0},{0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0},{0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0},{0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0},{0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0},{0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0}};    
boolean N1[8][8] PROGMEM = {{0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0},{0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0},{0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0},{0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0},{0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0},{0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0},{0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0},{0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0}};
boolean N2[8][8] PROGMEM = {{0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0},{0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0},{0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0},{0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0},{0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0},{0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0}};
boolean N3[8][8] PROGMEM = {{0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0},{0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0},{0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0},{0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0},{0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0},{0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0}};  
boolean N4[8][8] PROGMEM = {{0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0},{0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0},{0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0},{1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0},{0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},{0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0},{0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0},{0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0}};
boolean N5[8][8] PROGMEM = {{0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0},{0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0},{0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0},{0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0},{0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0},{0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0},{0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0},{0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0}};  
boolean N6[8][8] PROGMEM = {{0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0},{0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0},{0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0},{0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0},{0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0},{0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0},{0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0},{0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0}}; 
boolean N7[8][8] PROGMEM = {{0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0},{0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0},{0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0},{0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0},{0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0}};    
boolean N8[8][8] PROGMEM = {{0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0},{0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0},{0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0},{0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0},{0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0},{0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0},{0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0},{0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0}};  
boolean N9[8][8] PROGMEM = {{0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0},{0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0},{0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0},{0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0},{0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0},{0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0},{0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0}};    

void setup() { 
  FastLED.setBrightness( BRIGHTNESS );
  FastLED.addLeds<WS2812B, DATA_PIN, RGB>(leds, NUM_LEDS);
}

void loop() {
  int counter = 0;
  for(int line=0;line<8;line++){
    for(int column=0;column<8;column++){
      if(N2[line][column]==1){
        leds[counter] = CRGB::Yellow; 
        FastLED.show();     
        delay(delayval);
      }

      if(N1[line][column]==1){
        leds[counter+64] = CRGB::Green; 
        FastLED.show();
        delay(delayval);
      }     
      
      counter++;
    }
  }
  while(1){};
}
```

Comment: Well done finding this out by yourself and for answering your own question ;-) FastLED is a very well developed library.